# Nopcommerce widget plugin dey

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce plugin development but am learning very fast.

I am developing a widget plugin to display vendor information box in product details page, but am having some issues, the product page stopped displaying and throwing errors.

Below and in this question will be my codes and picture of the product page error.

Contoller:

```cs
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult PublicInfo(string widgetZone, Vendor vm, object additionalData)
{
        ActionResult actionResult;
        EmptyResult emptyResult = new EmptyResult();
        var activeStoreScopeConfiguration = this.GetActiveStoreScopeConfiguration(this._storeService, this._workContext);
        VendorDetailsSettings VendorDetailsSetting = _settingService.LoadSetting<VendorDetailsSettings>(activeStoreScopeConfiguration);
        if (VendorDetailsSetting != null)
        {
           int QproductId = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["productId"]);


           var productId = Convert.ToInt32(additionalData);
            if (productId != 0)
            {
                Product productById = _productService.GetProductById(productId);
                if (productById == null ? false : productById.VendorId != 0)
                {
                    Vendor vendorById = _vendorService.GetVendorById(productById.VendorId);

                    if (vendorById == null || vendorById.Deleted ? false : vendorById.Active)
                    {
                        var Model = new PublicInfoModel();
                        //Model.Id =  vendorById.Id;
                        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Vendor), "x");
                        Model.Name = LocalizationExtensions.GetLocalized<Vendor>(vendorById, Expression.Lambda<Func<Vendor, string>>(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(typeof(Vendor).GetMethod("Name").MethodHandle)), new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression }));
                        parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Vendor), "x");
                        Model.Description = LocalizationExtensions.GetLocalized<Vendor>(vendorById, Expression.Lambda<Func<Vendor, string>>(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(typeof(Vendor).GetMethod("Description").MethodHandle)), new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression }));
                        Model.SeName = SeoExtensions.GetSeName<Vendor>(vendorById);
                        PublicInfoModel model = Model;
                      if (VendorDetailsSetting.ShowVendorEmail || VendorDetailsSetting.ShowVendorPhoneNumer || VendorDetailsSetting.ShowVendorVendorRating)
                        {
                            model.Email = vendorById.Email;


                        }
                      return View("~/Plugins/Widgets.VendorDetails/Views/PublicInfo.cshtml", model);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        actionResult = emptyResult;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    actionResult = emptyResult;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                actionResult = emptyResult;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actionResult = emptyResult;
        }
        return actionResult;
    }
```

Plugin.cs:

```cs
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_vendorDetailsSettings.WidgetZone) ? new List<string>() : new List<string> { _vendorDetailsSettings.WidgetZone };
}


public void GetConfigurationRoute(out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    actionName = "Configure";
    controllerName = "WidgetsVendorDetails";
    routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary { { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.VendorDetails.Controllers" }, { "area", null } };
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a route for displaying widget
/// </summary>
/// <param name="widgetZone">Widget zone where it's displayed</param>
/// <param name="actionName">Action name</param>
/// <param name="controllerName">Controller name</param>
/// <param name="routeValues">Route values</param>
public void GetDisplayWidgetRoute(string widgetZone, out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    actionName = "PublicInfo";
    controllerName = "WidgetsVendoDetails";
    routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.VendorDetails.Controllers"},
        {"area", null},
        {"widgetZone", widgetZone}
    };
}


public override void Install()
{
    var settings = new VendorDetailsSettings
    {
        WidgetZone = "productbox_add_info"
    };
    _settingService.SaveSetting(settings);
    base.Install();
}

public override void Uninstall()
{
    _settingService.DeleteSetting<VendorDetailsSettings>();
    base.Uninstall();
 }   
}
```

Comment: what are the errors your are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The error was the product page didn't implement IControllers... But I have resolved it..  By Returning base. View() instead or just views... 
 Thanks.